# How can I drive Junkrat's Rip Tire up walls?

Tags: overwatch

Today I was matched against a Junkrat who killed me several times. One time, he used his Rip Tire to kill me, but from the Kill Cam, the Rip Tire seemed to be climbing walls and other props to get to me.

I tried playing Junkrat and tried to replicate the same thing, and yet my tires won't go up the walls? How do I drive Junkrat's Rip Tire up walls?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Without changing the options, as Yuuki below points out, you can hold your <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> key to climb walls manually.

If you want it to climb walls automatically, you'll need to head on to:

- Options menu
- Controls menu
- Select **Junkrat** from the All Heroes list.

Scroll down, and you should see the option *Rip Tire Automatically Climbs Walls*, which will allow his ult to climb walls.

[image]

Comment: You can actually climb walls without enabling this option. It works essentially like Hanzo's and Genji's wall-climbing abilities: press and hold space to climb walls. This option merely does the same thing that Hanzo's and Genji's hero-specific options do, let you climb walls without holding space.

Comment: @Yuuki You learn something new every day. I had no idea that's how you climbed walls; I assumed that the option actually prevented you from climbing up walls in the first place.